# Can't Access Imported Class Method

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

I am trying to create a new Path using the following method:

```
Path path = new Paths.get(path_name);
```

I've imported both *Path* and *Paths* and I have confirmed that the method *get* exists in Paths, but Eclipse is telling me that the method does not exist. It says: **Paths.get cannot be resolved to a type**
What should I do? I restarted Eclipse and my PC but still no luck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `new`: it is a static method.

Comment: Maybe `get()` accept a different parameter-type than `path_name` ? You should post the full code - help us help you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet is incorrect: invoking a static method does not require `new`

```
Path path = Paths.get(path_name); // get(...) is a static method
```

Comment: 'This class consists exclusively of static methods' [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)

Comment: *Facepalm* I knew that. Thanks. Sat for 20 minutes trying to figure out something as simple as this :P

Comment: Also Paths().get() will not work because Paths has a private constructor.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thanks, I didn't know `Paths` is a system class. It got introduced after I switched away from Java.

Comment: @user1885631 This is fixed, see my comment above.

Answer (score 4):

`get(..)` is a static method. Call it like this:

```
Path path = Paths.get(path_name);
```

Cite:
'This class consists exclusively of static methods' 
[API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)